# interpreting results of beta regression

Tags: multiple-regression, beta-regression

Looking here at the beta reg packge:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf

The code below is using a categorical batch variable and a continuous temp variable to predict yield which is (0,1).  How does one interpret the coefficients. For example:

(1) batch1 has a coefficient of 1.72.  This does NOT mean batch1 increases yield by 1.72%, relative to batch10-the reference group,  because yield is 
between 0 and 1. Since the default betareg uses the logit link it appears the coefficient 1.72 is the log odds ratio and exp(1.72)= 5.58 is the odds ratio AND the interpretation is (using the odds ratio) that the batch 1 odds of "....." is 5.58 times higher than batch 10 the reference group.

I left "....." blank because if this was a typical logistic regression with 2 outcome categories (high yield and low yield) I would say the odds of batch 1 being in the high yield outcome category is 5.58 times higher than the odds of batch 10 the reference group. BUT with a beta regression the outcome is continuous so I cannot say "odds of batch 1 being in the high yield outcome category" because in a beta regression there is no category. SO what do you say:  the batch 1 odds OF WHAT? is 5.58 times higher than the referecce group batch10.

(2) SImilarly for temp.,  increasing temp by 1 degree increases the odds OF WHAT? by  1.01 [exp(.01)] times?

(3) Apart from the vignette link above. Can you provide any references for intuitive explanations of the beta regression model?  Can you the beta regression model have an identity link vs. logit? Intuitively what is the motivation for the logit link in the beta regression model?

Thank you.

```
> library(betareg)
> data("GasolineYield", package = "betareg")
> gy_logit <- betareg(yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield)
> summary(gy_logit)

Call:
betareg(formula = yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8750 -0.8149  0.1601  0.8384  2.0483 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -6.1595710  0.1823247 -33.784  < 2e-16 ***
batch1       1.7277289  0.1012294  17.067  < 2e-16 ***
batch2       1.3225969  0.1179020  11.218  < 2e-16 ***
batch3       1.5723099  0.1161045  13.542  < 2e-16 ***
batch4       1.0597141  0.1023598  10.353  < 2e-16 ***
batch5       1.1337518  0.1035232  10.952  < 2e-16 ***
batch6       1.0401618  0.1060365   9.809  < 2e-16 ***
batch7       0.5436922  0.1091275   4.982 6.29e-07 ***
batch8       0.4959007  0.1089257   4.553 5.30e-06 ***
batch9       0.3857930  0.1185933   3.253  0.00114 ** 
temp         0.0109669  0.0004126  26.577  < 2e-16 ***

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(phi)    440.3      110.0   4.002 6.29e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood:  84.8 on 12 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.9617
Number of iterations: 51 (BFGS) + 3 (Fisher scoring)
```

Comment: Didn't you ask essentially the same question last summer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297659/interpretation-of-betareg-coef My answer hasn't changed ;-) As for the reason for the logit link: The motivation for the link function (as well as for the beta response distribution itself) is more often than not statistical. It assures predictions in the unit interval and often fits well.

Comment: I posted again using he data from the betareg example and because this question is better.  can you answer or can you answer in the previous question- the  1 unit increase in temp increases the odds ratio of what? by .04%?  when explaining the results to lay people they will not understand the previous answer.

Comment: But please don't just ask again but follow up on the original question and also point out specifically what is still unclear. This will avoid duplication of efforts...