# Standardised coefficient interpretation (beta reg. with logit link)

Tags: r, logit, standardization, beta-regression

If I standardize the coefficients (`scale()` command in R) of a beta regression with a logit link, how do I interpret them? I would say:

> Of how many standard deviations (SD) the log odds of the y changes for a one SD increase in the covariates.

But is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Standardizing the coefficients $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_k$ with `scale()` does not make sense. This would subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation *across the coefficients*: $\tilde \beta_j = (\beta_j - \bar \beta)/\mathrm{SD}(\beta_1, \dots, \beta_k)$.

Multiplying $\beta_j$ with the standard deviation of the corresponding regressor $\mathrm{SD}(x_j)$ would have the same effect as standardizing the regressor $x_j$ (e.g., with `scale()`). This makes sense if you want to capture the marginal effect of a *one standard deviation change* in $x_j$ as opposed to a *one unit change* in $x_j$.

Additionally, you might find this answer about [interpretation of betareg coef](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297659/interpretation-of-betareg-coef) useful.

Comment: To clarify, does this mean that multiplying the beta coefficient by the standard deviation of the predictor gives you a standardized beta that is comparable with standardized coefficients from other types of regression models, e.g. GLMs?

Comment: Yes, this behaves the same way as other models based on linear predictors.